# Regex everything between two strings multiple times

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String like

```
[{"id":"9","label":"P","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["606","610","614","618","622","625","629"]},{"id":"8","label":"M","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["607","611","615","619","626","630"]},{"id":"7","label":"G","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["609","613","617","621","624","628","632"]},{"id":"36","label":"GG","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["608","612","616","620","623","627","631"]},{"id":"152","label":"XGG","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["3713","6577","6578","6579","6580","6581","6582"]}]
```

What i need is the label values: P, M, G, GG, XGG. i tried to get everything between label and a comma, but its not working

> "(label)(.*)(,)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?<=label\"\:)\"\w+\"
```

this will do it

or if you really want to parse it as json

do this

```
var arr = [];
var jso = [{"id":"9","label":"P","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["606","610","614","618","622","625","629"]},{"id":"8","label":"M","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["607","611","615","619","626","630"]},{"id":"7","label":"G","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["609","613","617","621","624","628","632"]},{"id":"36","label":"GG","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["608","612","616","620","623","627","631"]},{"id":"152","label":"XGG","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["3713","6577","6578","6579","6580","6581","6582"]}];
console.log(jso.length);
for(var i=0;i<jso.length;i++){
    arr.push(jso[i].label);
}
console.log(arr);
```

regex demo : http://regex101.com/r/kT9kE6

Answer (score 4):

This string is in the JSON format and hence it is recommended to use a JSON parser rather than using regex

Read about JSON format in http://www.json.org/.

This link provides explains about JSON in java http://www.json.org/java/

Comment: Thank you, i know its in JSON but i cant use a parser, that comes as a String object from a web crawler that i cannot change.

Comment: You can parse the JSON content present in a string

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is greedy.

Change it to lazy

`label.*?,`

You can also use conditional regex to fetch only the label values

Regex using conditional expression

`(?<="label":")\w+`

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fP6lS8)

Comment: Krishna M the demo in your link shows only the first occurrence of label is selected

Answer (score 0):

**You should probably use a JSON parser**, however...

This regex will capture all the labels in a group names "labels"

```
.*?(?:label)":"(?<labels>[^"]+)+.*?
```

Or depending how you are executing this, just search for this match

```
(?:label)":"(?<labels>[^"]+)
```

You can see it working here: http://regex101.com/r/fS8jA8

And the resulting JAVA (generated by regex101):

```
String re = "(?:label)\\":\\"(?<labels>[^\\"]+)";
String str = "[{\"id\":\"9\",\"label\":\"P\",\"price\":\"0\",\"oldPrice\":\"0\",\"products\":[\"606\",\"610\",\"614\",\"618\",\"622\",\"625\",\"629\"]},{\"id\":\"8\",\"label\":\"M\",\"price\":\"0\",\"oldPrice\":\"0\",\"products\":[\"607\",\"611\",\"615\",\"619\",\"626\",\"630\"]},{\"id\":\"7\",\"label\":\"G\",\"price\":\"0\",\"oldPrice\":\"0\",\"products\":[\"609\",\"613\",\"617\",\"621\",\"624\",\"628\",\"632\"]},{\"id\":\"36\",\"label\":\"GG\",\"price\":\"0\",\"oldPrice\":\"0\",\"products\":[\"608\",\"612\",\"616\",\"620\",\"623\",\"627\",\"631\"]},{\"id\":\"152\",\"label\":\"XGG\",\"price\":\"0\",\"oldPrice\":\"0\",\"products\":[\"3713\",\"6577\",\"6578\",\"6579\",\"6580\",\"6581\",\"6582\"]}]
";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
```